# Static Polymorphism Issue

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, static-memory-allocation

I am on a micro controller (which means I can only have static memory allocation) and I am trying to work with inheritance.....

Suppose I have a abstract class `Image` and an abstract class `Font`.  An instance of `Font` can return an `Image` based off of the `char` given in a function like so:

```
Font* mf;
Image* image = mf->GetImage("a");
```

Now the real issue is I have no idea what to do for the `GetImage` Function.

The problem is this: in c++ for you to have a member of an abstract class you have to use it as a pointer.  So my dilemma is that I have a `Font` which wants to create a new `Image` and then return it.

If it returns a pointer to its newly created `Image` you are returning a reference to a temporary object:

```
Image* FontImpl::GetImage(char c){
  return &ImageImpl(c);  //This object is destroyed once this function exits
}
```

And then if I return I try to return an actual type like this:

```
Image FontImpl::GetImage(char c){
  return ImageImpl(c);   //Cannot cast from ImageImpl to Image
}
```

So is there an idiom or something for this kind of static memory problem?

Comment: What's _static inheritance_ actually? Did you mean _static polymorphism_ as provided with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I meant static polymorphism.... I will edit the post accordingly

Comment: Using abstract base classes is runtime polymorphism not static polymorphism.  You're doing static memory allocation.  Though if that gets unwieldy you might want to explore writing or downloading a small memory pool class so do some dynamic allocation from a static buffer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic allocation would be easiest but if that's not possible, you have to store the instance somewhere outside the function, e.g.:

```
static ImageImpl image;

Image& FontImpl::GetImage(char c) {
  image = ImageImpl(c);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: Should return `Image*` and `&image`, and worth mentioning whatever use of the "returned" image is needed should be completed before `GetImage` is called again as it will overwrite the earlier-returned image.